# allow edit of custom post type but not regular posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles, capabilities

Is it possible to set the capabilities of a role to allow editing of a custom content type but not editing of the regular post types? If so, how would I go about doing that? Thanks!

Comment: For all users or for a specific user or role?

Comment: Hi Brad, for a role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could install one of many plugins like this to restrict access for different user roles http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/

Or you could remove the admin menu links to any items you want for a specific user using PHP code.

Comment: Thanks brad! I thought about removing the links from the admin panel but I was concerned that a sneaky user could just go straight to the create new page by guessing the direct link. Or am I overthinking this?

Comment: You can remove access to everything and only leave the CPT menu item http://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/

Comment: Basically I have a custom type organization and users will be associated with one org per user. An org can be associated to many users. Each user should be able to edit only the org post they are associated to and not be able to edit regular posts.  What do you think is the best way to accomplish that?

Comment: Plugin is the easiest otherwise here's the code http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9505/hide-admin-menus-per-role-in-wordpress

Comment: One last question. If I remove the cap to edit posts, that will also remove cap to edit custom posts too right, even if I give a role to a user to edit the custom type? Do you have to have the ability to edit posts to edit custom type posts?

Comment: No. You can be more specific with access for different roles so they can edit CPT's but not regular post and page type.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12291/discussion-between-trey-eckels-and-brad-dalton)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me - with no plugins.
User that is allowed to edit/add only posts from custom type 'job':

```
add_action( 'current_screen', 'jobs_block_edit' );
function jobs_block_edit() {
    global $current_screen;

    $restricted = current_user_can('job_user') && (
            ($current_screen->base=='edit' && $current_screen->id!='edit-job') || 
            ($current_screen->base=='post' && $current_screen->id!='job')
        );

    if ($restricted) {
        exit( wp_redirect( home_url( '/' ) ) );
    }
}
```